# Apparent incorrect value from variable definition?

Tags: vba, variables, definition

New to VBA and lousy at it, so please be gentle!

I have the following code which gives the Long type variable "EIa" a value.  I was getting a bunch of odd results later down the code so I put in some Debug.Print lines to find my issue and notice that when I Debug.Print the variable EIa, I get 0 but if I Debug.Print EXACTLY the expression that defines EIa, I get the expected value.  Code below, any ideas?

```
        'Calculate mA1:
'****************************************************************************************************
EIa = Etimber * ImatA / (Etimber * (ImatA + ImatB + ImatC + ImatD))
Debug.Print "EIa = "; EIa
Debug.Print "EIa = "; Etimber * ImatA / (Etimber * (ImatA + ImatB + ImatC + ImatD))
mA1 = 12 * 0.5 * (q1PSF * EIa) * bMat * LcantiA ^ 2 '12 puts this into lb-in
    If LmatSymA = 0 Then
        fbA1 = 0
    Else
        fbA1 = (mA1 * (0.5 * tMatA) / ImatA)
    End If
```

Comment: All variables are Long type.

Comment: Copy/Paste from the Immediate window:                                                         EIa =  0 
EIa =  0.333333333333333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the expression is a kind of fractional, floating point number, but since you defined EIa as Long (a large integer), it gets truncated to zero upon assignment.
See [Visual Basic Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx).

Comment: BOOM! done, thank you.  It was just doing what I told it to do, I just didn't understand what the hell I was telling it!

Comment: You're welcome.  Will you please upvote and accept my answer, then?  As you can see we both need some cred.